# Angular app cant connect to NodeJS/SocketIO backend cors issue?

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io, cors

Im traying to connect my Angular App with my NodejS Backend using SocketIoModule in my Angular appication but im getting an error in the browser

[image]

my Backend

```
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: ':'
}))

const http = require('http');
const server = http.Server(app);

const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const io = socketIO(server);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`started on port: ${port}`);
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');
    
});
io.on('new-message', (message) => {
    io.emit(message);
});
```

Module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3000', options: {} };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This shuld trigger the 'connection' event on the server but instad it trow the error in the browser console

Comment: probably a silly question but have you tried removing: app.use(cors({
    origin: ':'
}))

Comment: i think i can scrape up an old working example i had if that helps.

Comment: I get the same error with or without it. if u find it that will be awsome @JBoothUA

Comment: ok it's older, if i recall correctly i wired it up using socket.io and Express web server and then wired that up to my IIS via IISNODE.  not sure if that is at all relevant, but I will post it

Comment: i actually just noticed something else, so I've posted some code and another theory :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The solution:

I create the server

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var port=3000;
// App setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`
    -------------Resume-------------------
    status:     listening
    port:       ${port}
    url:        http://localhost:${port}
    --------------------------------------`);
});

// Socket setup
var io = socket(server);

// Listen for new connection and print a message in console 
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log(`
    ------------New connection---------------------
    
    Connection ID:   ${socket.id}
    IP:              ${socket.handshake.address}
    Time:            ${socket.handshake.time}
    ----------------------------------------------`)

    // Listening for chat event
    socket.on('chat', function(data){
        
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
    });

    // Listening for typing event
    socket.on('typing', function(data){
        console.log('typing event');

        io.sockets.emit('typing', data);
    });

});
```

Then import **socket.io-client** and **@types/socket.io-client ** into my angular project
and create a **WebSocketService** to handle the emits and listeners
and add the service to the providers and the **HttpClientModule** to imports in the ***modules.ts***.

***webSocketService.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class WebSocketService {
    socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;

    constructor() {
        this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    }

    listen(eventname: string) : Observable<any> {
        return new Observable((subscriber) => {
            this.socket.on(eventname, (data) => {
                subscriber.next(data);
            })
        })
    }

    emit(eventname: string, data: any) {
        this.socket.emit(eventname, data);
    }
}
```

***module.ts***

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WebSocketService } from './web-socket.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [WebSocketService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to attach some working code as promised, but I might have just noticed something...  The error message mentions port 3000 and ALSO port 4200, it looks like your socket is open on port 3000, so I wonder if you could track down where the 4200 is coming from?

---

In reply to your comment:
I believe that Socket.IO is used to connect Client <-> Server.  So there may be an issue with your configuration.  Are you sure you want different ports? as you mentioned you want 2 servers, but my guess would be you really want 1 port and 1 server, running 1 app that has Client <-> Server communication?
Anyways if I am off there, it may just be possible because of the different ports / servers that the CORS error is actually valid here and you'd have to figure out how to add CORS headers to your web server:

Example:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

would allow communication to/from ANY client

---

And here is an older working example of a chatroom I built if you would like to try to compare code.

app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var socket = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

socket.on('connection', function (io) {
    io.on('ioChatMessage', function (msg) {
        socket.emit('ioChatMessage', msg);
    });
});

http.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

index.html

```
<ul id="Messages"></ul>
<form action="">
    <input id="Message" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="button" id="Send" value="Send" />
</form>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $.getScript('socket.io/socket.io.js', function () {
        initSocket();
    });

    var initSocket = function () {
        var socket = io();

        $('#Send').click(function () {
            var userNameTag = $('#UserNameTag');
            var nameTag = userNameTag.html();
            if (nameTag) {
                socket.emit('ioChatMessage', { text: nameTag + ':  ' + $('#Message').val(), style: userNameTag[0].style });
            } else {
                socket.emit('ioChatMessage', { text: $('#Message').val() });
            }

            $('#Message').val('');
            return false;
        });

        socket.on('ioChatMessage', function (msg) {
            $('#Messages').append($('<li>').text(msg.text).css(msg.style));
        });

        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            socket.disconnect();
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: If i make a js file such as your **Index.js** and load it as a response to an url it works i know it cos i made one already but i want to connect that server with an Angular app @JBoothUA, when i do it like that works cos is on the same port but my Angular app its in 4200 and the backend is on 3000

Comment: Server port:3000 and AngularApp Port:4200

Comment: something about that seems off no...?   shouldn't they be running on the same port?

Comment: it seems like maybe you have 2 apps really running maybe?  a dev angular web server and a dev node web server.  i think you're going to want the node server to serve the angular app (when in the real world) and the dev angular web server is used just for testing the angular app standalone?

Comment: Yes @JBoothUA , I have 2 applications running independently, what I want to achieve is to make them communicate without being on the same port, pretending that they are on different servers, I saw some videos on YouTube and everything worked fine, I don't know what happens.

Comment: ok I have never tried that.  I believe that Socket.IO is used to connect Client <-> Server.  So there may be an issue with your configuration.  Are you sure you want different servers?? or did you mean Client <-> Server?  Anyways if I am off there, it may just be possible because of the different servers that the CORS error is valid here and you'd have to figure out how to add headrs. i will add them to my answer.

Comment: please upvote or accept if you thnk I have helped :)

Comment: **Client<->Server** Sorry, thats what im traying but to do :( look i did  exactly what this video says earlier and i had the same result the cors block @JBoothUA

Comment: if you are going for Client <-> Server, then I believe there should just be only 1 port.  the client and the server will then talk via a socket on that port.

Comment: i think you need to load the angular app into an HTML file.  just load up the js files that are created via ng build into that HTML file and then put <app-root> or something like that in the HTML body.  and then serve that HTML file (and your angular app js files) via your NODE web server.  that should serve up your angular app on 1 port.  you should then be able to hit that port via a web browser (the client) and perform socket communication

Comment: this should take your angular dev web server port out of the equation.. i believe you're running 2 separate applications right now.  you will want to run 1 application on 1 port (for the server) and then you can use a browser to represent the client(s), but it's still really 1 application running on 1 port

Comment: I think that can work ill try it put thtat on a response in case it works 

Comment: ok thanks, if it helps please upvote and/or accept my answer :).  if you run into any issues let me know. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using socket.io v.3.x, check this page: https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/index.html, in particular, the section about CORS handling.

You should implement your application like something like this:

```js
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://example.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true
  }
});
```

Also make sure your socket.io versions match.